# Install python packages in docker Alpine base image

Tags: python, docker, alpine-linux

I have requirement to install python packages from requirements.txt file in docker.
I am using "python:3.10.10-alpine" as my base image and installing the packages from requirements.txt file.
Here is my docker file for refernce:

```
FROM python:3.10.10-alpine

RUN apk update && \
    apk add --no-cache wget && \
    apk add --no-cache build-base libffi-dev openssl-dev && \
    apk add python3 py3-pip gcc musl-dev

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade pip

COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
```

and in my requirements.txt bunch of python modules are mentioned, including scipy, numpy and others.

While installing the packages it returns error as:

```
#10 1305.7 ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==2.11.0 (from versions: none)
#10 1305.7 ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==2.11.0
#10 ERROR: process "/bin/sh -c pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
------
 > [5/5] RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt:
1157.3   Installing build dependencies: still running...
1220.5   Installing build dependencies: still running...
1293.2   Installing build dependencies: still running...
1304.1   Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
1304.1   Getting requirements to build wheel: started
1304.8   Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
1304.8   Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
1305.5   Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
1305.7 ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==2.11.0 (from versions: none)
1305.7 ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==2.11.0
------
Dockerfile:11
--------------------
   9 |     
  10 |     COPY requirements.txt .
  11 | >>> RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
```

I tried running the requirements.txt without any mention of Versions, but it didn't work.

Comment: The base image already contains Python. Is there any reason why you install another Python?

Comment: Furthermore the whole `RUN apk...` command should be rewritten because `apk update` contradicts `apk add --no-cache`.

Answer (score 0):

The Docker stuff is running fine, it's actually the combination of packages that is the problem.

```
1305.7 ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==2.11.0 (from versions: none)
1305.7 ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==2.11.0
```

Whatever combination of python version and package versions you have, this `tensorflow==2.11.0` does not work. As packages get updated, they can become contradictory to eachother. For example, your numpy version may be dependent on something in `tensorflow==2.12.0` and by specifying `2.11.0` it causes issues.

One way to resolve this is letting `pip` resolve all the versions. So go to your `requirements.txt` file, and change
`tensorflow==2.11.0` to `tensorflow`. By not specifying version, pip will install the latest suitable version and resolve any internal conflicts.

Comment: Hello, I tried installing without mention of any version, but it didn't installed and throws similar error. I guess its the issue with the base image itself. Because I installed all packages with python-slim base image.